# What are other names for planetoids that aren't orbiting a solar system, but hurtling through space?

Tags: asteroids, terminology

I'm trying to think of a good word for an asteroid/planetoid that has no stable orbit but has been ejected from a system and is passing close to a sun. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange watercollider.  I think your question could be cleaned up a little.  Isn't a planetoid an asteroid?

Comment: Are you looking for an existing alternative or do you want a new one?

Comment: ["A rogue planet (also termed an interstellar planet, nomad planet, free-floating planet, unbound planet, orphan planet, wandering planet, starless planet, or sunless planet) is a planetary-mass object that orbits a galactic center directly."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet)

Comment: I'd recommend that you consider their orbits *open, unbound or non-periodic*, but not "unstable". In orbital mechanics "unstable" usually applies only to *closed, bound, and periodic* orbits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See nnnnnn's comment below.

The [NASA website](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/small-asteroid-or-comet-visits-from-beyond-the-solar-system), describing ['oumuamuam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOumuamua), uses the term "interstellar object." Extrasolar asteroid would seem to be another option.  I haven't seen a unique word different from asteroid that originated outside of the solar system.

It seems a simple prefix is sufficient to describe objects beyond the solar system, i.e. exoplanet.

Scienfitic American has an [article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/two-interstellar-intruders-are-upending-astronomy/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=daily-digest&utm_content=link&utm_term=2019-11-27_featured-this-week&spMailingID=61644144&spUserID=MTE1NjM1NDM5MjAwS0&spJobID=1764375774&spReportId=MTc2NDM3NTc3NAS2) which uses the term "interstellar object."

Also, see answers to:

- [Is intrastellar commonly used by astronomers to refer to objects within our solar system?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33680/7982)
- [Adjective for things outside our solar system](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30131/7982)

Comment: Isn't *exoplanet* normally used to describe planets that orbit stars other than our Sun? As compared to *rogue planets*, which do not orbit a star.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yup, you are right.  You should write that as an answer and not just as a comment.

Comment: Well I don't think it is a complete answer because it doesn't apply to smaller objects. I guess *rogue* could also be applied to asteroids and so forth, but I didn't post an answer because I don't have sources I can quote to back that up.